# Pyinstaller Unable to access Data Folder

Tags: python, pygame, pgzero

Below is the game.spec file that I have created.
When running the below command, the app gets created perfectly

```
pyinstaller --onefile game.spec
```

When operating the game, it is unable to locate any of the datafiles. On further exploration found that it searches for all the datafiles in the directory /Users/username and not from the absolute path the program runs from.

Does the spec file need to be written differently?

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['game.py'],
             pathex=['/Users/username/pythonenv/mygame'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('images','images'),
('fonts','fonts'),
('sounds','sounds'),
('pygame','pygame'),
('pygameMenu','pygameMenu'),
('pgzero','pgzero'),
('numpy','numpy'),
('pgzrun.py','.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='game',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='game')
app = BUNDLE(coll,
             name='game.app',
             icon=None,
             bundle_identifier=None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When pyInstaller (or cx_Freeze, py2exe, etc.) make an executable, all the program files, along with PyGame, Python and a bunch of other stuff is all compressed up.

When it's run, the first thing to happen is that archive of stuff is unpacked.  Unpacked *somewhere*.  Then your executable is started, but not from the location of the unpack.

To fix this, your script has to determine the location it is running from - that is the full path to the script.  Then use this location to find all the program's extra files.

```
import sys
import os.path

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    EXE_LOCATION = os.path.dirname( sys.executable ) # cx_Freeze frozen
else:
    EXE_LOCATION = os.path.dirname( os.path.realpath( __file__ ) ) # Other packers
```

Then when loading a file, determine the full path with `os.path.join`:

```
my_image_filename = os.path.join( EXE_LOCATION, "images", "xenomorph.png" )
image = pygame.image.load( my_image_filename ).convert_alpha()

my_sound_filename = os.path.join( EXE_LOCATION, "sounds", "meep-meep.ogg" )
meep_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound( my_sound_filename )
```

It may be possible to use `os.chdir( EXE_LOCATION )` to set the directory once, and thus make less changes, but I think  being careful about paths is the best approach.

Comment: Thanks @Kingsley, this has resolved the issue with regard to the resources